# nsfetchedresultscontroller sort sections base on item count

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nssortdescriptor

I use the code below to do a fetch result from `branch` table in a country:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"BranchData" inManagedObjectContext:[BRCoreRepository instance].managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:5];

    NSString *cache = nil;

    if (searchValue.length > 0){
        fetchRequest.predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" city contains[cd] %@ || address contains[cd] %@ || branchCode contains[cd] %@ ",searchValue,searchValue,searchValue];
    } else cache = @"_preditc_state";

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"branchState" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor ]];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                    managedObjectContext:[BRCoreRepository instance].managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"branchState"
                                                                               cacheName:cache
                                 ];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

In the current code I could create sections based on the `branchState` of the branch. It is working correctly, but I have another problem - I want to order the items based on section item count too. So if in state `B` we have 200 items but in section `A` we have 150 items in the result we would show section `B` above section `A`. Is this possible with `NSFetchedResultsController` too?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to model the relationship count in your parent class. This can be automated by overriding the setters of the relationship in your `NSManagedObject` subclass.